# Why can't I get the right horizontal axis labels on my ggplot2 chart?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, charts

I am trying to do a faceted plot of a grouped dataframe with ggplot2, using geom_line(). My dataframe has a Date column and I would like to have dates on the horizontal axis. If I just use Date in aes(x=Date, ...) I get nice labels on the horizontal axis. However, the line has an almost horizontal section where the date jumps from the end of one group to the beginning of the next group. This code and chart shows that:

```
dts <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by="day")

mos <- sapply(dts, month)

df <- data.frame(Date=dts, Month=mos)

nr <- nrow(df)

df$X <- rep(1, nr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month) -> dfgrp
dfgrp %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(Time = Date[1:n()],
         Z = cumsum(X)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Z)) +
  geom_line(color="darkgreen", size=0.5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Month, scale="free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, size=7))
```

[image: Chart using Date on the horizontal axis]

I would not like my chart to have those almost-horizontal lines when the date changes by a large amount. I was able to generate a chart without those lines using integers on aes() as follows:

```
dfgrp %>%
  mutate(Time = 1:n() %>% as.integer(),
         Z = cumsum(X)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Z)) +
  geom_line(color="darkgreen", size=0.5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Month, scale="free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from=1, to=nr, by=10) %>% as.integer(),
                     labels = function(x) as.character(dfgrp$Date[x])) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, size=7))
```

The line on the chart looks like I want it but the dates on the horizontal axis are not correct: they end in February 2020 in every facet while the dates in the dataframe end in December 2021 and the dates in the first chart begin and end on different months in different facets.

[image]

I tried many things but nothing worked. Any suggestions on how to have a chart with dates like in the first chart above and lines like in the second chart above?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have dates in 2020 and 2021 - do you want those to appear as two separate series across the same time scale?

Comment: @JonSpring - No. I want a single line as it appears in my second chart. I just want to put appropriate labels on that chart without changing anything else.

Comment: You are using 1:n() as the x so that is being shown as Jan 1 1970 (day 1 in Date format) to around early March for each month.

Comment: It sounds like you want the Jan facet to start from Jan 1 and proceed for 62 days (31 for 2020 and 31 more for 2021) to March 2nd? That seems confusing to me, since the 2nd half would be shown as Feb when it is actually another Jan.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to adjust the dates to be in the same year, but noting the original year as a variable:

```
library(lubridate)
dfgrp %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date),
         adj_date = ymd(paste(2020, month(Date), day(Date)))) %>%
         # 2020 was leap year so 2/29 won't be lost
  mutate(Time = Date[1:n()],
         Z = cumsum(X)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=adj_date, y=Z, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line(size=0.5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Month, scale="free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, size=7))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. But I need the lines to be straight like in my second chart.